# create google spreadsheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create spreadsheet using google script.I am getting bellow error message:

**Cannot use "DriveApp.createFile()" to create Google MIME types.**

Here is my below code to create spreadsheet.

```
 directory.createFile(searchFileName,"",MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
```

Here is my screen shot of error ,message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> After extensive consideration, we have determined that
>   DriveApp.createFile() should not be used to create MimeType.GOOGLE_*
>   files.  Shortly, attempting to do so will fail and result in a more
>   descriptive error message.

You can't create MimeType.GOOGLE_* files with the default DriveApp Service, you need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (which you should enable in the Script Editor by selecting Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console.), take a look at the [official answer here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4080#c21).

Here's an example:

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = {
    "title": "My Spreadsheet",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": "{YOUR_FOLDER_ID}"
      }
    ]
  };
 Drive.Files.insert(ss);
}
```

You can find the list of the Supported MIME Types [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).

It's also possible to create new Google Sheet files with 
[Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) and the [create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) method:

```
function myFunction(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("My Spreadsheet");
 Logger.log(ss.getUrl());
}
```